# How can I move a captured variable into a closure within a closure?

Tags: closures, rust

This code is an inefficient way of producing a unique set of items from an iterator. To accomplish this, I am attempting to use a `Vec` to keep track of values I've seen. I believe that this `Vec` needs to be owned by the innermost closure:

```
fn main() {
    let mut seen = vec![];
    let items = vec![vec![1i32, 2], vec![3], vec![1]];

    let a: Vec<_> = items
        .iter()
        .flat_map(move |inner_numbers| {
            inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(move |&number| {
                if !seen.contains(&number) {
                    seen.push(number);
                    Some(number)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

However, compilation fails with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
 --> src/main.rs:8:45
  |
2 |     let mut seen = vec![];
  |         -------- captured outer variable
...
8 |             inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(move |&number| {
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the `move`s, a mutable borrow would've been fine. But for some reason I don't fully understand the borrow checker won't allow it (if the `seen.push` call is removed, it compiles fine). I suggest trying to boil the problem down a bit and filing an issue. `flat_map` is *the* cause for most of the confusing borrow checker errors I've gotten so far

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a little surprising, but isn't a bug.

[`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) takes a `FnMut` as it needs to call the closure multiple times. The code with `move` on the inner closure fails because that closure is created multiple times, once for each `inner_numbers`. If I write the closures in explicit form (i.e. a struct that stores the captures and an implementation of one of the closure traits) your code looks (a bit) like

```
struct OuterClosure {
    seen: Vec<i32>
}
struct InnerClosure {
    seen: Vec<i32>
}
impl FnMut(&Vec<i32>) -> iter::FilterMap<..., InnerClosure> for OuterClosure {
    fn call_mut(&mut self, (inner_numbers,): &Vec<i32>) -> iter::FilterMap<..., InnerClosure> {
        let inner = InnerClosure {
            seen: self.seen // uh oh! a move out of a &mut pointer
        };
        inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(inner)
    }
}
impl FnMut(&i32) -> Option<i32> for InnerClosure { ... }
```

Which makes the illegality clearer: attempting to move out of the `&mut OuterClosure` variable.

---

*Theoretically*, just capturing a mutable reference is sufficient, since the `seen` is only being modified (not moved) inside the closure. However things are too lazy for this to work...

```
error: lifetime of `seen` is too short to guarantee its contents can be safely reborrowed
 --> src/main.rs:9:45
  |
9 |             inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(|&number| {
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: `seen` would have to be valid for the method call at 7:20...
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
7 |       let a: Vec<_> = items.iter()
  |  _____________________^
8 | |         .flat_map(|inner_numbers| {
9 | |             inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(|&number| {
10| |                 if !seen.contains(&number) {
... |
17| |         })
18| |         .collect();
  | |__________________^
note: ...but `seen` is only valid for the lifetime  as defined on the body at 8:34
 --> src/main.rs:8:35
  |
8 |           .flat_map(|inner_numbers| {
  |  ___________________________________^
9 | |             inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(|&number| {
10| |                 if !seen.contains(&number) {
11| |                     seen.push(number);
... |
16| |             })
17| |         })
  | |_________^
```

Removing the `move`s makes the closure captures work like

```
struct OuterClosure<'a> {
    seen: &'a mut Vec<i32>
}
struct InnerClosure<'a> {
    seen: &'a mut Vec<i32>
}
impl<'a> FnMut(&Vec<i32>) -> iter::FilterMap<..., InnerClosure<??>> for OuterClosure<'a> {
    fn call_mut<'b>(&'b mut self, inner_numbers: &Vec<i32>) -> iter::FilterMap<..., InnerClosure<??>> {
        let inner = InnerClosure {
            seen: &mut *self.seen // can't move out, so must be a reborrow
        };
        inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(inner)
    }
}
impl<'a> FnMut(&i32) -> Option<i32> for InnerClosure<'a> { ... }
```

(I've named the `&mut self` lifetime in this one, for pedagogical purposes.)

This case is definitely more subtle. The `FilterMap` iterator stores the closure internally, meaning any references in the closure value (that is, any references it captures) have to be valid as long as the `FilterMap` values are being thrown around, and, for `&mut` references, any references have to be careful to be non-aliased.

The compiler can't be sure `flat_map` won't, e.g. store all the returned iterators in a `Vec<FilterMap<...>>` which would result in a pile of aliased `&mut`s... very bad! I *think* this specific use of `flat_map` happens to be safe, but I'm not sure it is in general, and there's certainly functions with the same style of signature as `flat_map` (e.g. `map`) would definitely be `unsafe`. (In fact, replacing `flat_map` with `map` in the code gives the `Vec` situation I just described.)

For the error message: `self` is effectively (ignoring the struct wrapper) `&'b mut (&'a mut Vec<i32>)` where `'b` is the lifetime of `&mut self` reference and `'a` is the lifetime of the reference in the `struct`. Moving the inner `&mut` out is illegal: can't move an affine type like `&mut` out of a reference (it would work with `&Vec<i32>`, though), so the only choice is to reborrow. A reborrow is going through the outer reference and so cannot outlive it, that is, the `&mut *self.seen` reborrow is a `&'b mut Vec<i32>`, not a `&'a mut Vec<i32>`.

This makes the inner closure have type `InnerClosure<'b>`, and hence the `call_mut` method is trying to return a `FilterMap<..., InnerClosure<'b>>`. Unfortunately, [the `FnMut` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) defines `call_mut` as just

```
pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

In particular, there's no connection between the lifetime of the `self` reference itself and the returned value, and so it is illegal to try to return `InnerClosure<'b>` which has that link. This is why the compiler is complaining that the lifetime is too short to be able to reborrow.

This is extremely similar to the `Iterator::next` method, and the code here is failing for basically the same reason that one cannot have an iterator over references into memory that the iterator itself owns. (I imagine a ["streaming iterator"](https://github.com/emk/rust-streaming) (iterators with a link between `&mut self` and the return value in `next`) library would be able to provide a `flat_map` that works with the code nearly written: would need "closure" traits with a similar link.)

Work-arounds include:

- the `RefCell` suggested by Renato Zannon, which allows `seen` to be borrowed as a shared `&`. The desugared closure code is basically the same other than changing the `&mut Vec<i32>` to `&Vec<i32>`. This change means "reborrow" of the `&'b mut &'a RefCell<Vec<i32>>` can just be a copy of the `&'a ...` out of the `&mut`. It's a literal copy, so the lifetime is retained.
- avoiding the laziness of iterators, to avoid returning the inner closure, specifically`.collect::<Vec<_>>()`ing inside the loop to run through the whole `filter_map` before returning.

```
fn main() {
    let mut seen = vec![];
    let items = vec![vec![1i32, 2], vec![3], vec![1]];

    let a: Vec<_> = items
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|inner_numbers| {
            inner_numbers
                .iter()
                .filter_map(|&number| if !seen.contains(&number) {
                    seen.push(number);
                    Some(number)
                } else {
                    None
                })
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                .into_iter()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

I imagine the `RefCell` version is more efficient.

Comment: Great answer! Very educational. An additional alternative would be to just write the code using for loops instead - it's arguably simpler than both workarounds, and probably more efficient

Answer (score 12):

<del>It seems that the borrow checker is getting confused at the nested closures + mutable borrow. It might be worth filing an issue.</del> Edit: See [huon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526154/155423) for why this isn't a bug.

As a workaround, it's possible to resort to `RefCell` here:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let seen = vec![];
    let items = vec![vec![1i32, 2], vec![3], vec![1]];

    let seen_cell = RefCell::new(seen);

    let a: Vec<_> = items
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|inner_numbers| {
            inner_numbers.iter().filter_map(|&number| {
                let mut borrowed = seen_cell.borrow_mut();

                if !borrowed.contains(&number) {
                    borrowed.push(number);
                    Some(number)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question after I ran into a similar issue, using `flat_map` and `filter_map`. I solved it by moving the `filter_map` outside the `flat_map` closure.

Using your example:

```
let a: Vec<_> = items
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|inner_numbers| inner_numbers.iter())
    .filter_map(move |&number| {
        if !seen.contains(&number) {
            seen.push(number);
            Some(number)
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
    .collect();
```