# Cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure as mutable

Tags: rest, rust, nickel

This is my first day with Rust, but I'm trying to do something trivial, and I'm stuck.

What I'm trying to do is to add an struct to a Vector, and return the result. What I'm trying is to create a very simple REST service which will store the data in memory when posting, and return all the data in JSON format when doing a GET.

This is my current code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    let mut reservations = Vec::new();

   server.post("/reservations/", middleware! { |request, response|
        let reservation = request.json_as::<Reservation>().unwrap();

        reservations.push(reservation); // <-- error occurs here

        format!("Hello {} {}", reservation.name, reservation.email)

    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:3000");
}
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521637/how-can-i-move-a-captured-variable-into-a-closure-within-a-closure) with a RefCell, but then I get the error that the trait Sync is not implemented for `Vec<reservation::Reservation>`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is a very good example of how Rust protects you from thread unsafety.

If you think about it, in your current code it would be possible that multiple threads try to concurrently mutate `reservations` without any kind of synchronization. This is a data race and Rust will complain about it.

A possible solution would be to wrap the `reservations` vector into a `Mutex` to get synchronization. You will also need an `Arc` (atomic reference counting), since Rust cannot prove that `reservations` will live longer than the threads.

With these changes, your code should be like the following:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    let reservations = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

    server.post("/reservations/", middleware! { |request, response|
        let reservation = request.json_as::<Reservation>().unwrap();

        reservations.lock().unwrap().push(reservation); // <-- error occurs here

        format!("Hello {} {}", reservation.name, reservation.email)

    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:3000");
}
```

You can check the documentation for additional info about [`Mutex`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and [`Arc`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).

Comment: favorite post ever, thank you very much Erik Pragt for the question and @aochagavia for the answer.

Comment: "this is a good example of how Rust forces you to write inefficient, verobose and complicated code for something that will only ever run on a single thread" (in many cases) 

Comment: @Dominic Precisely: I'm a Rust-newbie writing a single-threaded app and am beating my head against the wall over this issue.