# Returning closures which capture outer variables in Rust

Tags: closures, rust, lifetime

As the title states I am looking to return a closure from a function which has some initial, mutable state. In the following examples `CowRow` is a `struct` with a `time` field. It also has a `String` field, so is thus not copyable. Concretely, I would like a function that looks something like:

```
pub fn agg1() -> Box<Fn(&CowRow)> {
    let res = 0;
    Box::new(move |r| { res += r.time; })
}
```

Of course, this produces the error:

```
src/queries.rs:9:25: 9:38 error: cannot assign to captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
src/queries.rs:9     Box::new(move |r| { res += r.time; })
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/queries.rs:9:14: 9:41 help: consider changing this closure to take self by mutable reference
src/queries.rs:9     Box::new(move |r| { res += r.time; })
                              ^~~~~~~~
```

It is my understanding that Rust needs to know about the size of returned values and because closures borrow their stack frame from their environment we need to introduce the `Box` and `move` to get a size for the return and put the closure on the heap.

Is there some way to also put `res` on the heap in this closures environment? Or otherwise allow for this behaviour? Of course I have looked at: [Cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559073/cannot-borrow-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure-as-mutable) but this seems overly complicated and it's not clear to me how this would perform in the case of multiple threads running this function simultaneously.

Another technique I tried was to change the closure to take a mutable reference to an `i32` which I can initialise outside of the `agg` function. Example:

```
pub fn agg0() -> Box<Fn(&CowRow, &mut i32)> {
    Box::new(move |r, &mut acc| { acc += r.time; })
}
```

However, this produces the error:

```
src/queries.rs:4:35: 4:48 error: re-assignment of immutable variable `acc` [E0384]
src/queries.rs:4     Box::new(move |r, &mut acc| { acc += r.time; })
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/queries.rs:4:35: 4:48 help: run `rustc --explain E0384` to see a detailed explanation
src/queries.rs:4:28: 4:31 note: prior assignment occurs here
src/queries.rs:4     Box::new(move |r, &mut acc| { acc += r.time; })
```

This one is a total mystery to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things here: make `res` mutable, and return an `FnMut` closure, not an `Fn` one:

```
pub struct CowRow {
    time: u64,
}

pub fn agg1() -> Box<FnMut(&CowRow) -> u64> {
    let mut res = 0;
    Box::new(move |r| { res += r.time; res })
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = agg1();
    let moo = CowRow { time: 2 };
    println!("{:?}", c(&moo));
    println!("{:?}", c(&moo));
    println!("{:?}", c(&moo));
}
```

The `Fn` trait forbids the implementor from changing itself when invoked.  Since this closure is modifying its own state, this means it cannot be `Fn` [1].  Instead, you need to use `FnMut` which *does* allow mutation of the closure's captured environment.

---

[1]: Unless you involve interior mutability, of course.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In this case is it correct that when we `move` the closure to the heap we are also moving a mutable version of it's environment because we have declared this as an `FnMut`? So, declaring the return type as `FnMut` has changed the semantics of `move`? Also, I'm not what you mean by `interior mutability`.

Comment: @Josh Data *itself* is not mutable or immutable in Rust; that's a property of how you access it.  That said, yes; the closure captures `res` by value, and since we move the closure on to the heap, the captured `res` goes with it.  Also, see [Interior vs. Exterior Mutability](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/mutability.html#interior-vs-exterior-mutability) from the book.

Answer (score 2):

[DK.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511686/234590) already said how to fix `agg1`, but I wanted to explain what's wrong with `agg0`, for completeness.

```
pub fn agg0() -> Box<Fn(&CowRow, &mut i32)> {
    Box::new(move |r, &mut acc| { acc += r.time; })
}
```

We can infer from `agg0`'s return type that the type of the closure's second parameter is `&mut i32`. `&mut acc` is a pattern that deconstructs the mutable reference, defining `acc` as an `i32`, initialized to a *copy* of the referenced value. You can't mutate it, because you didn't define `acc` to be mutable (you'd need to write `&mut mut acc` instead of `&mut acc`), but that's not what you want anyway, because then you'd be mutating a copy. What you want is to mutate the pointed-to integer, so you need to define your closure like this:

```
pub fn agg0() -> Box<Fn(&CowRow, &mut i32)> {
    Box::new(move |r, acc| { *acc += r.time; })
}
```

Here, the type of `acc` is `&mut i32`, so in order to mutate the `i32`, we need to dereference the pointer first (this yields an lvalue that refers to the `i32` behind the pointer; it's *not* a copy!).

Comment: This is great. Thanks for adding more details to the answer!