# Listen for keyboard input and process data

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write an application that listens for keyboard input, detects barcode
scans, and submits that data to an HTTP endpoint. For now, I'm struggling with the simple problem of capturing data from a scan. I've tried using the [device_query](https://docs.rs/device_query/latest/device_query/) package but struggled with very inaccurate data. [inputbot](https://crates.io/crates/inputbot) is providing more accurate results, but I cannot figure out some basic issues with borrowing and accumulating data in a Vec.

```
use inputbot::KeybdKey;

fn main() {
    let mut chars = Vec::new();
    let c = ",".to_string();

    KeybdKey::bind_all(|event| {
        if event == KeybdKey::Numrow1Key || chars.first().unwrap() == "1" {
            // start collecting chars
            if event == KeybdKey::EnterKey {
                println!("{:?}", &chars);
                chars.retain(|event| event == &c);
            } else {
                chars.push(inputbot::from_keybd_key(event).unwrap().to_string());
            }
        } else {
            println!("Something... {:?}", event);
        }
    });

    inputbot::handle_input_events();
}
```

From here, I just get the compile error: the trait bound `&mut Vec<String>: Copy` is not satisfied. I've tried using `move` as well as collecting to a `char` Vec and a `KeybdKey` Vec, but it makes no difference. I've tried using Arc/Mutex as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559073/cannot-borrow-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure-as-mutable), but it still errors out. It's unclear to me how this is a memory safety protection when my application is a single-threaded application with only one access to the `chars` variable at a time.

Error Message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut Vec<String>: Copy` is not satisfied in `[closure@src\main.rs:10:24: 22:6]`
   --> src\main.rs:10:5
    |
10  |       KeybdKey::bind_all(|event| {
    |  _____^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_-
    | |     |
    | |     within `[closure@src\main.rs:10:24: 22:6]`, the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `&mut Vec<String>`
11  | |         if event == KeybdKey::Numrow1Key || chars.first().unwrap() == "1" {
12  | |             // start collecting chars
13  | |             if event == KeybdKey::EnterKey {
...   |
21  | |         }
22  | |     });
    | |_____- within this `[closure@src\main.rs:10:24: 22:6]`
    |
    = note: `Copy` is implemented for `&std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`, but not for `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src\main.rs:10:24: 22:6]`
note: required by a bound in `KeybdKey::bind_all`
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message to the question?

Comment: The error has been added.

Comment: [The function `bind_all`](https://github.com/obv-mikhail/InputBot/blob/2245b7ada826d159aabb1f16291115dd54d790b7/src/public.rs#L157) requires the closure to be `Fn(KeybdKey) + Send + Sync + Copy + 'static`.

Comment: The `Copy` bound here is problematic. If the closure moves `Arc<Mutex<Vec<_>>>` into itself, then it is no longer a copyable closure (it's `Clone` but not `Copy`). I can't think of an elegant way to solve this. Is the `Copy` bound really necessary for the library?

Comment: [I opened a PR](https://github.com/obv-mikhail/InputBot/pull/58) on the repository of InputBot as an attempt to fix this.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki thank you! I appreciate you help me feel like I'm not going insane!