# How to save a closure in a Struct with a mutable reference to outside the struct?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I am trying to make an stack machine where that can take a closure for the output like this:

```
pub struct VirtualMachine {
    stack: Vec<isize>,
    code: Vec<Op>,
    code_pointer: usize,
    io_dest: Box<dyn Fn(isize)>,
}

impl VirtualMachine {
    pub fn new(io_dest: Box<dyn Fn(isize)>) -> VirtualMachine {
        VirtualMachine { stack: vec![], code: vec![], code_pointer: 0, io_dest }
}
```

Normaly i want it to just print the results like this `|x:isize|println!("{}",x)`. But for testing i want to catch the output in a variablle:

```
#[test]
fn test_simple_add() {
    let code = vec![Op::Push(1),Op::Push(2),Op::Add];
    let mut io= Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
    let io_closure=Box::new(|x:isize|io.lock().unwrap().push(x)); //<-- error borrowed value does not live long enough
    let mut virtual_machine = VirtualMachine::new(io_closure);
    virtual_machine.run();
    assert_eq!(3, io.lock().unwrap()[0]);
}
```

But i am running in some difficulties.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559073/cannot-borrow-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure-as-mutable) tells me i have to put my io array in Arc<Mutex<>>.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831944/how-do-i-store-a-closure-in-a-struct-in-rust) gave me the idea to put the Closure in a Box.
But i have no idea how to make it work together and why i get the error.
Error message:

```
   --> src\virtual_machine.rs:98:45
    |
98  |         let io_closure=Box::new(|x:isize| {         io.lock().unwrap().push(x); });
    |                                 ---------   ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                                 |
    |                                 value captured here
99  |         let mut virtual_machine = VirtualMachine::new(io_closure);
    |                                                       ---------- cast requires that `io` is borrowed for `'static`
...
102 |     }
    |     - `io` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why is io not living long enough? Isn't io alive until the end of the test and has the same lifetime as my closure?
Is there a better way to do what i am trying to do (Passing a closure to a struct which can mutate a varibale outside the struct)?

Comment: Please add the full error message as reported by `cargo check` (not an IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix your problem by cloning ptr and moving it into closure like this

```
fn test_simple_add() {
    let code = vec![Op::Push(1),Op::Push(2),Op::Add()];
    let mut io= Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
    let io_clone = io.clone();
    let io_closure=Box::new(move |x:isize| io_clone.lock().unwrap().push(x)); //<-- error borrowed value does not live long enough
    let mut virtual_machine = VirtualMachine::new(io_closure);
    virtual_machine.run();
    assert_eq!(3, io.lock().unwrap()[0]);
}
```