# Passing data as mutable into add_probe?

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I want to mutate some data in the pad.

I see an example of working with pads here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/0.18.8/examples/src/bin/pad_probes.rs#L40

It seems like I can only use callbacks that don't modify anything they capture since the callback type is `func: F` . I tried to simply use one of my variables inside the closure and got this:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `self.frame_id`, as `Fn` closures cannot mutate their captured variables
   --> src/decoding_branch.rs:161:13
    |
161 |             self.frame_id += 1;
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
```

How I'm supposed to change anything in pads?

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I should use something like [Cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559073/cannot-borrow-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure-as-mutable)

I tried the following to check this approach

```
        let frame_id = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
        
        nvv4l2dec_src.add_probe(gst::PadProbeType::BUFFER, move |_, probe_info| {
            let mut frame_id = frame_id.lock().unwrap();
            *frame_id += 1;
            println!("{:?}", frame_id);
            });
```

and it seems like it works.

Comment: `Arc<Mutex>`? This is too much. Use `Cell` if you can, or `Atomic*` if you cannot. The `Arc` isn't needed at all.

Comment: Cell doesn't work in this case since this callback works in a different thread, but thanks for this comment, I learned a little bit more about rust.

Comment: Then use atomics.