# How to use closures in a nested map?

Tags: closures, rust

I am trying to make a 2-dimensional matrix from a functor that creates each element, and store it as a flat `Vec` (each row concatenated).

I used nested `map` (actually a `flat_map` and a nested `map`) to create each row and concatenate it. [Here is what I tried](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3d61ca851d17a7be106b&version=stable):

```
fn make<T, F>(n: usize, m: usize, f: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: Fn(usize, usize) -> T,
{
    (0..m).flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(|x| f(x, y))).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v = make(5, 5, |x, y| x + y);

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error during compilation:

```
error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:45
  |
5 |     (0..m).flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(|x| f(x, y))).collect()
  |                                    ---      ^ -          - borrowed value needs to live until here
  |                                    |        | |
  |                                    |        | borrowed value only lives until here
  |                                    |        borrowed value does not live long enough
  |                                    capture occurs here
```

How does one use closures in nested maps? I worked around this issue [by using a single map on `0..n*m`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ee962e3d7c8f40e03f0e&version=stable), but I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28521637/155423 ?

Comment: I hoped since y:usize was Copy-able, it could be taken by value by the inner closure, thus avoiding the need for any borrowing...

Comment: I agree, and I'm a bit surprised that there's an error here at all — I have a feeling it has to do with that `FnMut`. There may also be a real bug, as sprinkling `.clone()` on all the variables doesn't fix the problem as I thought it would either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case the inner closure `|x| f(x,y)` is a borrowing closure, which takes its environment (`y` and `f`) by reference.

The way `.flat_map(..)` works, it forbids you to keep a reference to `y`, which is not from the outer scope. Thus we need to have your closure take its environment by value, which is not a problem for `y` being a `usize` which is `Copy`:

```
(0..m).flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(move |x| f(x, y))).collect()
```

However, now another problem arises:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
 --> src/main.rs:5:36
  |
1 | fn make<T, F>(n: usize, m: usize, f: F) -> Vec<T>
  |                                   - captured outer variable
...
5 |     (0..m).flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(move |x| f(x,y))).collect()
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Here, we are trying to move `f` as well into the closure, which is definitely not possible (unless `m` is `1`, but the compiler cannot know that).

Since `f` is a `Fn(usize, usize) -> T`, we could just as well explicitly pass a `&` reference to it, and `&` references are `Copy`:

```
fn make<T, F>(n: usize, m: usize, f: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: Fn(usize, usize) -> T,
{
    let f_ref = &f;
    (0..m)
        .flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(move |x| f_ref(x, y)))
        .collect()
}
```

In this case, the closure takes its environment by value, and this environment is composed of `y` and `f_ref`, both of them being `Copy`, everything is well.

Comment: You could also write "fn make<T,F>(n: usize, m: usize, ref f: F) -> Vec<T>" to take a reference to the closure.

Comment: Perfect! I got confused by the second error, I didn't realize it was talking about f...
@A.B.: Nice! I keep forgetting about patterns in function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Levans's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30659346/155423), another way of defining the function would be

```
fn make<T, F>(n: usize, m: usize, f: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: Fn(usize, usize) -> T + Copy,
{
    (0..m).flat_map(|y| (0..n).map(move |x| f(x, y))).collect()
}
```

Since we know that `|x, y| x + y` is a `Copy` type, `f` would get copied for every callback that `flat_map` invokes. I would still prefer Levans's way as this would not be as efficient as copying a reference.