# Cannot move out of captured variables in an `FnMut` closure

Tags: rust

```
pub fn create_future(
    notificator: mpsc::Sender<usize>,
    proxy: Proxy,
) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    proxy.something()
        .and_then(move |sub| {
            sub.for_each(move |a| { // <---- Closure A
                proxy.something_else(a)
                    .and_then(move |b| { // <---- Closure B
                        notificator.send(b.len());  // <---- Error!
                        Ok(())
                    })
                    .or_else(|e| {
                        panic!("oops {}", e);
                        Ok(())
                    })
            })
        })
        .map_err(|e| {
            ()
        })
}
```

This doesn't compile because

```
.and_then(move |b| {
          ^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

My understanding of the error is:

1. Closure B is `FnMut`, and it captures `notificator` by taking its ownership
2. In Closure B, `send` again needs to take the ownership
3. Now both `send` and Closure B are modifying `notificator` thus the error.

Is my understanding right? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `Proxy`? Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: "In Closure B, send again needs to take the ownership" - That doesn't sound right. `mpsc::Sender::send` takes `&self`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How can I move a captured variable into a closure within a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28521637/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nested closures are tricky.

Consider this:

```
fn use_a_fn_multiple_times(f: impl Fn(String)) {
    f("foo".to_owned());
    f("bar".to_owned());
}

fn use_fn_once(f: impl FnOnce() -> Vec<u8>) {
    println!("Bytes: {:?}", f());
}

fn main() {
  use_a_fn_multiple_times(|a: String| {
    use_fn_once(move || a.into_bytes());
  });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=546cd8a5fe8085a34ed29d0202e106f2)

Notice that the inner closure captures `a` by move. This is fine. The outer closure owns `a` and can do with it what it wants, including moving it into the inner closure (which, because it consumes its captured value, is a `FnOnce`).

The outer closure is called multiple times, each time with a new string, and every time a new inner closure capturing this string is created.

But what if what you want to capture comes from even further out?

```
fn use_a_fn_multiple_times(f: impl Fn(String)) {
    f("foo".to_owned());
    f("bar".to_owned());
}

fn use_fn_once(f: impl FnOnce() -> Vec<u8>) {
    println!("Bytes: {:?}", f());
}

fn main() {
  let outer_s = "see:".to_owned();

  use_a_fn_multiple_times(|a: String| {
    use_fn_once(move || {
        let mut v = outer_s.into_bytes();
        v.extend(a.into_bytes());
        v
    });
  });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7f4e4e744abb33fad7a5f5556a32475f)

Then you get the error you're seeing (except for `Fn` vs `FnMut`, which is immaterial to the problem). The inner closure is created anew on every call to the outer closure (it has to be, because it has to capture `a` every time), but it tries to capture `outer_s` by move every time. This can't work; after the first time, `outer_s` is moved from and thus invalid.

To map this back to your code, it's wrong to say "Closure B captures `notificator`", because there isn't just one Closure B. There's as many as necessary, however often your nested `and_then` and `for_each` calls will end up in that piece of code. But only one can ever capture by move.

So to solve this, you either need to make sure there's only one Closure B, or make sure you have enough `mpsc::Sender`s for everyone.

The first way is done by pulling the closure out of the nested context.

```
let closure_b = move |b| {
    notificator.send(b.len());
    Ok(())
};
proxy.something()
    .and_then(move |sub| {
        sub.for_each(move |a| { // <---- Closure A
            proxy.something_else(a)
                .and_then(closure_b)
                .or_else(|e| {
                    panic!("oops {}", e);
                    Ok(())
                })
        })
    })
    .map_err(|e| {
        ()
    })
```

except that won't work, since now Closure A faces the same issue, so you have to do it multiple times:

```
let closure_b = move |b| {
    notificator.send(b.len());
    Ok(())
};
let closure_a = move |a| {
    proxy.something_else(a)
        .and_then(closure_b)
        .or_else(|e| {
            panic!("oops {}", e);
            Ok(())
        })
};
proxy.something()
    .and_then(move |sub| {
        sub.for_each(closure_a)
    })
    .map_err(|e| {
        ()
    })
```

The second way involves a lot of `clone()` calls, and since I can't type-check your code, I won't attempt to write it.

When all is said and done, though, your code will still fail, because you're moving out of `Proxy` while also trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. I end up fixing it by adding `clone()`s.

Comment: Or in my case, when I want to using a `struct` that needs to be called with top level arguments within a nested `FnMut ` then I first annotate that struct with `#[derive(Clone)]` to be able to use `clone()`.